# Devo usar Thread.sleep() para meu programa não ocupar o processador?

Tags: java

Tenho um pequeno grupo de classes que implementam um jogo de Snake com dois jogadores, o jogo está funcionando como esperado. Porém eu estou utilizando um `while` infinito que está operando na velocidade máxima que o JVM permite, então se deixar a aplicação aberta por 10 segundos já começa a dar problema pro processador.

Atualmente está assim:

```java
    public void tick() {
        if (p1.snakeBody.size() == 0) {
            p1.criarSnake(new Right(), new Coordenada(10, 10));
            p2.criarSnake(new Left(), new Coordenada(30, 5));
        }
        ticks++;
        if (ticks > 200000) {   //aqui está o problema
            ticks = 0;
            p1.proximaPosicao();
            p2.proximaPosicao();
            if (p1.snakeBody().size() > 15) {
                p1.snakeBody().remove(0);
                p2.snakeBody().remove(0);
            }
        }

    /**
     * Cria a Thread que inicia o jogo
     */
    public void start() {
        Thread t = new Thread(this, "game loop");
        t.start();
    }

    /**
     * O jogo fica rodando enquanto os dois jogadores tiverem mais de zero vidas.
     */
    public void run() {
        while(p1.vidas != 0 && p2.vidas != 0) {
            tick();
            repaint();
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nThe winner is: " + p1.vitorioso(p2) + "!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Mas dessa maneira o computador precisa calcular os loops e condicionais 200000 vezes para apenas um movimento! Eu li a documentação sobre Threads, mas tem umas coisas de concorrência que não entendi muito bem, acho que o que eu busco é mais simples.

Tem como utilizar o método `Thread.sleep()` para evitar que o processador trabalhe tanto por tão pouco?

Comment: O que deseja fazer só vai piorar a situação. Não pode ficar em um laço fazendo isso o tempo todo, só execute quando for necessário. A arquitetura toda está errada.

Comment: Você tem alguma recomendação de leitura? Gostaria de aprender arquitetar de maneira correta

Comment: Não me lembro de nada sobre isso.

Comment: não tem um modo de só executar após um timer? Tipo fazer uma vez a cada 250ms

Comment: Tem, mas não conheço Java profundamente pra te dizer sobre.

Comment: Não sei se é o que vc procura, mas já tentou usar um [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa contagem de ticks é desnecessária. Como o Maniero falou, a arquitetura está errada. Também essa thread aí é desnecessária. Somente é necessário chamar (agendar) `repaint()` no *Event Dispatch Thread* (EDT) periodicamente.

Você pode usar o `Thread.sleep()` após o `repaint()`. É uma forma de fazer. Está certo? Não está. Trata-se de uma gambiarra.

Não sei lhe responder ao certo como fazer, pois não domino muito programação de jogos. O hkotsubo bem lembrou sobre [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) nos comentários, acredito que seja uma solução válida.

Penso que você deveria buscar uma solução que fosse mais robusta e eficiente. Sugiro pesquisar sobre jogos em Java ou Java Swing ou JavaFX ou então perguntar em https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ sobre como fazer o loop de desenho da tela.

Sugeri anteriormente o `ExecutorService` e agendar (*schedule*) a execução de um evento de desenho na tela a cada X milissegundos, mas não tenho certeza se seria uma boa solução. Acredito que o Timer seja uma melhor solução.

Comment: Tem coisas que só testando, no repaint provavelmente ajudaria, mas nada como um teste por parte do próprio AP, até pra ver qual taxa afeta, é valido lembrar que o repaint, assim como outros eventos em um "jogo" deve isolar funcionalidades especificas para impedir que uma tenha que esperar outra, como o controle do usuário, as flags da direção e a propria atualização dos "frames", mas isso depende muito do que é feito, não sou da área de jogos para afirmar tudo e nem se existe "receita de bolo" pra tal.

Comment: Eu tenho uma certa noção porque já brinquei de programação de jogos e programei multithread em sistemas que ficavam em loop, então a resposta não é desprovida de base. Tanto que achei exagerado receber downvote nela, de quem quer que tenha sido, afinal ela não está errada. Então não acho que só testando, são sugestões que funcionam, é uma resposta baseada em experiência.

Comment: Eu também cheguei a usar o `java.util.concurrent.Executors` pra controlar a concorrência, acaso exista múltiplas operações de diferentes fontes, talvez em um jogo multiplayer ajuda-se, mas só estou especulando, no meu caso foi um servidor HTTP que criei em Java. PS: o downvote não é meu, não sei qual a motivação também.